# Show that $U\cup W$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if $U \subset W$ or $W \subset U$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $U$ and $W$ be subspaces of $V$. Show that $U\cup W$ is a subspace of $V$ if  and only if $U \subset W$ or $W \subset U$.

I am not sure what I can do with the assumption that $U\subset W$ or $W \subset U$ to get started. If I could get a hint pointing me in the right direction, that would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: With that assumption, the result immediately follows. If either one of them is inside the other, then the union is just the "biggest" of the two, which we already know is a subSPACE

Comment: In the other direction, if $U\not\subset W$ and $W\not\subset U$, you can choose $u\in U\setminus W$ and $v\in W\setminus U$.  Can you then prove from there that  $U\cup W$ is not closed under addition?

Comment: @MatthewDaly thanks

Comment: @ArturoMagidin that post looks helpful, thanks. I am not sure if it is a duplicate and can let you know after reviewing everything

Comment: This result is actually true for groups and subgroups.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes that post is a duplicate, please close the thread thank you

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $U\cup W$ is a subspace. There are two possibilities

- If $U\subseteq W$ then we are done.
- If not, let $u\in U\setminus W$ be fixed. We will show that $W\subseteq U$. For every $w\in W$, we have both $u\in U\cup W$ and $w\in U\cup W$, so $u+w\in U\cup W$. Since $W$ is a subspace, $w\in W$ and $u\not\in W$, then $u+w\not\in W$. Therefore $u+w\in U$. Since $u\in U$, then $w=(u+w)-u\in U$ as well.

In both cases, $U\subseteq W$ or $W\subseteq U$.

Comment: what does the $U \setminus W$ notation mean?

Comment: @EvanKim It is set difference: $U\setminus W=\left\{u\in U:u\not\in W\right\}$. Maybe you've seen it as $U-W$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that $U\not\subset W$ and $W \not\subset U$ and $U\cup W$ is a subspace.

Then there exist $v \in U$ such that $v\not\in W$ and $w\in W $ such that $w \not\in U$, since $U \cup W $ is a subspace $u+w \in U \cup W$. This implies that $u+w$ belongs to $U$ or in $W$.

But this would force $v \in W$ or $w \in U$. Hence the assertion follows.

Comment: There is no need to prove this by contradiction; prove it by contrapositive. Your argument shows that if $U\not\subseteq W$ and $W\not\subseteq U$, then your $u+w$ does not lie in $U\cup W$, hence $U\cup W$ is not a subspace.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin agreed.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you for pointing out the the error. I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

One direction is straightforward.

Suppose $U \cup W$ is a subspace and $W \not \subset U$. Then there is some $w_0 \in W \setminus U$.

Now pick $u \in U$ and note that $u-w_0 \in U \cup W$ (since a subspace) and
$u-w_0 \in W $ (otherwise we would have $w_0 \in U$). Hence $u = (u-w_0) + w_0 \in W$
and so $U \subset W$.

Answer (score 0):

#### Proof $U\setminus W\neq\{\emptyset\}$ and $W\setminus U\neq\{\emptyset\}$ implies $U\cup W$ not a subspace of $V$

Suppose there are $u\in U\setminus W$ and $w\in W\setminus U$. Then $u+w\notin U\cup W$ (we know $u+w\notin U$ because that would imply $w\in U$, being $U$ a subspace, and we can show similarly that $u+w\notin W$).
Therefore, there are $u,w\in U\cup W$ such that $u+w\notin U\cup W$, hence $U\cup W$ is *not* closed under addition and thus not a subspace.

#### Proof that $U\cup W\le V$ implies $U\subseteq W$ or $W\subseteq U$

This is just another way to prove the same statement as above.

For all $u\in U, w\in W$, we have $u+w\in U\cup W$. For each such $u,w$, either $u+w\in U$ or $u+w\in W$ (or both). If $w\notin U$, then $u+w\notin U$ (because $u+w\in U$ would imply $(u+w)-u=w\in U$), and therefore $u+w\in W$, which implies $u\in W$.

We conclude that the existence of some $w\in W\setminus U$ implies $u\in W$ for all $u$, that is, $U\subseteq W$. Similarly, one proves that if $U\subseteq W$ is false then $W\subseteq U$.